# Delete XML nodes in SQL server based on conditions

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have xml that looks like

```
<MeasureSet>
    <MeasureSetType val_type="name">Variant</MeasureSetType>
    <Measure>
      <MeasureType val_type="name">single nucleotide variant</MeasureType>
      <AttributeSet>
        <MeasureAttributeType val_type="name">HGVS</MeasureAttributeType>
        <Attribute>NM_000054.4:c.838dupT</Attribute>
      </AttributeSet>
      <Citation>
        <CitationType val_type="name">general</CitationType>
        <ID Source="PubMed">10820168</ID>
      </Citation>
      <Citation>
        <CitationType val_type="name">general</CitationType>
        <ID Source="PubMed" />
      </Citation>
      <Citation>
        <CitationType val_type="name">general</CitationType>
        <ID Source="PubMed">9773787</ID>
      </Citation>
      <Citation>
        <CitationType val_type="name">general</CitationType>
        <ID Source="PubMed">18726898</ID>
      </Citation>
      <Citation>
        <CitationType val_type="name">general</CitationType>
        <ID Source="PubMed" />
      </Citation>
    </Measure>
  </MeasureSet>
```

I want to delete the Citation element nodes that have Citation/ID/@Source = "PubMed" and Citation/ID is empty

This deletes only the ID element, but the correct ones

```
SET @myBlob.modify('delete //Citation/ID[@Source = ''PubMed''
      and string-length(string(number(.))) = 0]')
```

and this deletes all Citation elements

```
SET @myBlob.modify('delete //Citation[ID/@Source = ''PubMed''
      and string-length(string(number(.))) = 0]')
```

Seems there should be an easy solution I'm not hitting on. Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your second one is checking the length of the wrong element - it's looking at `(.)`, which is here the `Citation` element (because it's in a predicate on the `Citation` element). Use instead

```
SET @myBlob.modify('
      delete //Citation[ID/@Source = ''PubMed'' 
                        and string-length(string(number(ID[1]))) = 0]')
```

where I have changed `.` to `ID[1]`. The `[1]` is needed because "`'number()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence)`".